# How can I create this disconnected block letter effect

Tags: text

[image]

I want to recreate the effect applied to "VINTAGE" in the image.

I thought it was just creating text with black stroke and duplicating it. Removing the stroke from the duplicate and then moving it to the desired position, but then I noticed that the stroke, if you will, is transparent.There is a gap between the two texts. hmmmm.

Is there a quick way to do this?

EDIT: Trying to get @AndrewH answer to work.

@AndrewH Thanks for the help, but I can't get it to work. I've followed word for word a few times and can't get it. I'll list what I have done. I use the type tool and type out the word. I then resize and add a 4pt stroke with the color red. Fill is black. I then select the text and - "object - transform - move" -4px, 4px and "copy". The new text is already selected. I send it to the back. And I remove the stroke. I use selection tool and select the original text (with stroke) and object - expand with stroke and fill options selected. I then select all on layer (both texts) and use "trim" option. All that happens is the red stroke disappears on the original.

Comment: Do you not want a gap between the 2 texts? I thought that is the point of the text effect. The area between the 2 type layers will have a transparent area.

Comment: Yes. A gap between the two texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method requires turning the text into outlines.

Write the text with the desired font. Add a stroke of a different color. I used a 4pt stroke.

Note: I also made the stroke on the outside in the strokes options panel but this may not be necessary.

[image: type with stroke]

Select the font and go to object -> Transform -> Move (Make sure to hit copy!). I did -4px, 4px. This depends on how much offset you want.

I then turned the type with the stroke into outlines (Object -> Expand, and then object -> Expand Appearance to expand the stroke and fill)

Select both type layers and open the path finder options. Select the "Trim" options (I had the type with the stroke on top). I then selected the direct select tool, clicked on the red part, went to Select -> Same -> Fill Color to select the other red parts and deleted.

result

[image: final result]

Note: My method requires you to make the text in outlines. If you want to do this effect with editable text then you will need to do each layer and make it into a new font.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewH ! I'm just a little confused. When I transform move (copy) both have strokes. Which one did you turn into outlines?

Comment: @john_911 turn off the stroke on the type layer you just made (was copied). In my example, I removed the stroke from the type layer that was moved 4px left, 4px down (so not the original type layer). I also moved the copied layer to the back.

Comment: Hmm, can't quite get it to work. First off my expand appearance is greyed out. I use expand to separate the fill and stroke. I've tried "trim" with the copied text and all the original (stroke and fill) just the stroke and just the fill and all don't seem to work. I'm still messing around with it though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but can't get it to work. I edited my post detailing what I do. Maybe you can spot where I am messing up. Thanks

Comment: Just got it. I had to expand the text one more time and then only select the red stroke part of the font and the entire text in the back and then do trim. Then delete the red stroke. Thank you